# Finding connectors for push button component

Tags: arduino-uno, button, wires

What type of connectors would I use for these buttons?:

http://www.adafruit.com/product/1477

They sell wires with the connectors already crimped on, but I only need the connectors.

I found https://www.jameco.com, but i'm not sure which connector would be right, or what to look for specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Go down to your local (decently-stocked) hardware store and ask for "quick connect terminals". From the dimensional drawing you'll need 2mm or 5/64" terminals.

Comment: You may not have to go to a hardware store for this as they can also be found online

Comment: These are also called "Quick Disconnect" connectors. Here is the category on [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-quick-connects-quick-disconnect-connectors/1442842) and [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Connectors/Terminals/_/N-5g5u?P=1yroslp). Jameco also sells them, but doesn't have a very easily filterable category for them.

Comment: Try the local automotive supplier. They should have crimp kits with those connectors included.